# display image after selecting the filename in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

Controller:

```
public function do_register()
{
    $path = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    $imgext=strtolower(strrchr($path,'.'));
    $imgname= $this->generateRandomString().$imgext;
    if($path!='')
    {
        $im= $this->config->item('base_url').'/uploads'.'/'.$imgname;
        $x=$this->do_upload($imgname);
        $data['img']=$im;
    }

    $this->search_model->register_user($data);
    $this->load->view('register_view');  
}

function generateRandomString()
{
    $characters = '0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
    $randomString = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < 8; $i++)
    {
        $randomString .= $characters[rand(0, strlen($characters) - 1)];
    }
    return $randomString;
}

function do_upload($img)
{
    $config['upload_path'] = './uploads/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
    $config['max_size'] = '575000';
    $config['file_name'] = $img;
    $this->load->library('upload',$config);
    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload('image'))
    {
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else
    {
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        return $data;
    }
    return;
}
```

This is the controller for image upload.When i select the image foe uploading   the image is not displayed while i selecting the filename?  what is the solution for this? How to display the image after selecting the filename?   Please provide a code for this?

Comment: You want to see image thumbnail before uploading ?

Comment: yes i want to see the  image preview  when i select the filename

Comment: correct me if i m wrong.you are selecting image from your local computer rite and you want to see image preview aftr selecting the image and before clicking submit button.

Comment: how to set the image upload size  and alert if size is greater than 1 mb??

Comment: check this [link](https://jsfiddle.net/usneo5dd/3/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Image preview before uploading check this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/lesson8/9NeXg/light/).

Code for limiting your upload size.

```js
  $(document).on('change','.coverimage',function(){
      files = this.files;
      size = files[0].size;
      //max size 50kb => 50*1000
      if( size > 1000141){
         alert('Please upload less than 1mb file');
         return false;
      }
      return true;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form role="form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="form-group">
      <label for="file">Choose your Image: </label>
      <input type="file"  class="coverimage" id="file1" name="file[]" multiple>
   </div>
   <button id='submit_btn' class="btn btn-default">upload</button>
</form>
```

Comment: idont want the code in jquery ,  i need the  answer in above  posted code  please  provide  solution for that

Comment: Your php code is fine.it will display error if image more than 575000kb is uploaded.

Comment: bt  when i upload the file  greater than  575000  it displays no error message. please provide solution for this issue??

Comment: for 1mb image This is not correct $config['max_size'] = '575000';

Comment: $config['max_size'] = '1048576 ';   is this correct?  
but when i upload the file greater than 1048576 it displays no error message. and file is uploaded.  what is the reason for this

Comment: Thanks for your reply . when  i upload the  file    greater than 1 mb ,   upload that 1 mb file  bt  display the eror  message  what is  the problem in this?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with javascript see [this](https://venugopalphp.wordpress.com/show-image-before-upload/). I hope it will help you.